# Can't install GeoDa in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install Geoda in my linux but I'm having some problem:

GeoDa: https://geodacenter.github.io/download_linux.html

```
$sudo dpkg -i geoda_1.18-1focal1_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 599099 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack geoda_1.18-1focal1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking geoda (1.18-1focal1) over (1.18-1focal1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of geoda:
 geoda depends on libgdal26; however:
  Package libgdal26 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package geoda (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.68ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 geoda
```

I tried to install the ligdal26 but I didn't succeed.

libgdal26: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libgdal26/download

```
$ sudo dpkg -i libgdal26_3.0.4+dfsg-1build3_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 599099 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libgdal26_3.0.4+dfsg-1build3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgdal26 (3.0.4+dfsg-1build3) over (3.0.4+dfsg-1build3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgdal26:
 libgdal26 depends on libarmadillo9 (>= 1:9.800.4+dfsg); however:
  Package libarmadillo9 is not installed.
 libgdal26 depends on libcfitsio8 (>= 3.470~); however:
  Package libcfitsio8 is not installed.
 libgdal26 depends on libdap25 (>= 3.20.5); however:
  Package libdap25 is not installed.
 libgdal26 depends on libhdf5-103; however:
  Package libhdf5-103 is not installed.
 libgdal26 depends on libjson-c4 (>= 0.13.1); however:
  Package libjson-c4 is not installed.
 libgdal26 depends on libnetcdf15 (>= 1:4.0.0); however:
  Package libnetcdf15 is not installed.
 libgdal26 depends on libpoppler97 (>= 0.86.1); however:
  Package libpoppler97 is not installed.
 libgdal26 depends on libproj15 (>= 6.0.0); however:
  Package libproj15 is not installed.
 libgdal26 depends on libqhull7; however:
  Package libqhull7 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libgdal26 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.33-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgdal26
```

Does anyone knows the solution? Or is GeoDa only avaiable to the LTS version?

Linux version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still can install GeoDa using commands below to get all the dependencies on Ubuntu 21.04:

```
cd ~/Downloads

wget -c https://github.com/GeoDaCenter/geoda/releases/download/v1.18/geoda_1.18-1focal1_amd64.deb

wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/armadillo/libarmadillo9_9.800.4+dfsg-1build1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cfitsio/libcfitsio8_3.470-3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libd/libdap/libdap25_3.20.5-1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gdal/libgdal26_3.0.4+dfsg-1build3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/hdf5/libhdf5-103_1.10.4+repack-11ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/json-c/libjson-c4_0.13.1+dfsg-7ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/netcdf/libnetcdf15_4.7.3-1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/poppler/libpoppler97_0.86.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/proj/libproj15_6.3.1-1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qhull/libqhull7_2015.2-4_amd64.deb

sudo apt update
sudo apt install ./geoda_1.18-1focal1_amd64.deb ./libgdal26_3.0.4+dfsg-1build3_amd64.deb ./libarmadillo9_9.800.4+dfsg-1build1_amd64.deb ./libcfitsio8_3.470-3_amd64.deb ./libdap25_3.20.5-1_amd64.deb ./libhdf5-103_1.10.4+repack-11ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./libjson-c4_0.13.1+dfsg-7ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb ./libnetcdf15_4.7.3-1_amd64.deb ./libpoppler97_0.86.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./libproj15_6.3.1-1_amd64.deb ./libqhull7_2015.2-4_amd64.deb
```

and then use GeoDa.

---

To have less problems in long-time periods you have to do a fresh installation of 20.04 LTS (long-term support, 5 years of updates) and live for 4 years without worries.

Comment: Thank u, It really solved my problem =).

Answer (score 3):

**Update :** I have tried the method from N0rbert and it work for me on Ubuntu 21.04.

In Ubuntu 21.04, I've installed `GeoDa` in a VirtualBox machine from an Ubuntu 20.04.3 ISO.

Another solution might be to create a USB key (Live or persistent) with Ubuntu 20.04.3 ISO. I've tested it with a live USB (you can install software but the configuration is reset when you reboot). I find it great for tests if I write the steps.

The following commands allow me to install `GeoDa` :

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 libpq5 libgdal26
```

Then I've clicked on `geoda_1.18-1focal1_amd64.deb` for installation and search for `GeoDa` in Applications.

[image]

Note : I'm an user of other Linux distributions. I've also installed `GeoDa` with Linux Mint 20.02 (it is based on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). I don't remember if the steps are the same. It was just a test.

I had no luck with `gdebi` to install directly on Ubuntu 21.04.

```
sudo gdebi geoda_1.18-1focal1_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libgdal26
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Linux version of Dependency Hell. Check the geoda website to see the prerequisites. Install them.

You could try installing the dependencies (and their dependencies) and ..., that will either work, or fail if the required version 17 of `foolib` is unavailable for your system.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing `geoda_1.18-1focal1_amd64.deb` using `gdebi`.

The `gdebi` utility automatically pulls in required dependencies.

First, install `gdebi`:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gdebi-core
```

Then install GeoDa using:

```
sudo gdebi geoda_1.18-1focal1_amd64.deb
```